# How can I remove certain string from file name?

Tags: shell, filenames, rename, cut

I have few files in the following directory: `/var/lib/jenkins/bin/`

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4430846 Apr 27 09:45 01-DSP-04.12_03_crc.bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1659036 Apr 27 09:45 01-FL4-04.12_02-crc.bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1659036 Apr 27 09:45 01-FL8-04.12_02-crc.bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1659036 Apr 27 09:46 01-FPGA-04.12_02-crc.bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  524328 Apr 27 09:46 01-MMI-04.11_05-crc.bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   27692 Apr 27 09:46 01-PIC-04.11_06-crc.bin
```

Also, I have a script that does some work at `/var/lib/jenkins/scripts/my_script.sh`.

**I want to remove the leading "01-" from the file names from this script. Is there any good way of doing this?**

I tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305134/remove-first-n-character-from-bunch-of-file-names-with-cut but do not work for me.

I get output like this:

Command

```
$ for file in /var/lib/jenkins/bin/*; do echo mv $file `echo $file | cut -c4-`; done
```

Output

```
mv /var/lib/jenkins/bin/01-DSP-04.12_03_crc.bin r/lib/jenkins/bin/01-DSP-04.12_03_crc.bin
mv /var/lib/jenkins/bin/test.sh r/lib/jenkins/bin/test.sh
```

As you can see it removes first 3 character which is directory name, not file name. I want to remove 3 character after 21 character from file name.

Any better way to do this?

Comment: You can use the string manipulation from bash in tandem with for loop as:  `for i in 01-?*; do mv -v "$i" "${i:3}"; done`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the full path, so that includes the directory. The simplest workaround is to first `cd` into the target directory and then run the `for` loop:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/bin
for file in *; do echo mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | cut -c4-)"; done
```

Or, using the shell's own [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) abilities:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/bin
for file in *; do echo mv "$file" "${file#????}"; done
```

Alternatively, if you have perl-rename (called `rename` on Debian-based systems, `perl-rename` on others) , you can do:

```
rename -n 's|.*/...||' /var/lib/jenkins/bin/*
```

Once you've made sure that works, remove the `-n` to make it actually rename.

---

However, as Sundeep pointed out in the comments, if you only want to remove `01-`, then remove that specifically:

```
rename -n 's|.*/01-||' /var/lib/jenkins/bin/*
```

Comment: typos... extra `"` in first command... should be 3 dots for rename... imo, using `echo mv "$file" "${file#01-}"` is safer.. deletes only if `01-` is present at start... and is easy to change instead of dealing with number of characters.. (assuming bash)

Comment: @Sundeep eeek! Wow, I was really not paying attention. Thanks!

Comment: And you could still do "${file#???}" to remove any first three chars without running `cut`

Comment: @ilkkachu OK, done.